# How to Remove Url Parameters and make english store as default

Tags: magento-1.9, php, multistore, redirect, store-view

i have a website with 4 different stores, English (default), french, Italian, German.

but the issue is when i had default settings in magento my urls contains that parameter "?___store=en"

but i searched online and came across this answer: http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magento-urls-remove-the-appended-store-parameter/

which is working fine for me but half. i have now store urls without any parameter.

but the issue i am facing is when i select English store it changes to url: http://www.smartteck.co.uk/en/ and when i remove

> /en/

from in front of url it directs me to french store.
i have tried by clearing caches and solution in other posts but nothing solved my issue.
can some one please tell me how keep my English store on base url http://www.smartteck.co.uk/  and rest of them should stay on url extension like /fr /de  /it etc and when some one visit our site http://www.smartteck.co.uk/ it must go to english store and (without any /en/) until he/she adds extension in url or change the language from drop down.
currently the hope page is opening in french
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set a store as default you should go to System > Manage Stores and click on your English store view.

Change its sort order to be first.

Also edit the parent store of your english store view and change the default store view to your english store view.

Comment: hi, it is already stating store view 0 for English, 1 for french, 2 Italian, 3 German. and can you tell me how to edit parent store view and from where? i will try doing that.

Comment: On the System > Manage Stores click on the middle column instead of the right one. Right column is the store view (french, english etc...), middle column is the store and left column is the website.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is already stating default store view "english"

Comment: Did you try to reindex / flush the cache ?

Comment: By the way, when I go to http://www.smartteck.co.uk/ I land on the english store so it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

System > Manage Stores >

In "Website"-Column - click your website name - set default store to your store

In "Store"-Column - click your store name - set default store view to your english store view

Go to System -> Indexing -> Reindex

Go to System -> Cache -> Clear Cache